# Get a part of text from TextView (java, Android)

Tags: java, android, textview

A work with Eclipse and now I'm creating an app and have a question: I have a TextView with text "A1=70; A2=72; A3=68; ...A10=74". How can I divide this text into parts and assign values 70, 72, 68 ...74 to the local variables A1, A2, A3 and A10?

...Thank you, guys, I found a decition! A little later I will tell about it.

Comment: Is `A1=70; A2=72; A3=68; ...A10=74` always remains same?

Comment: No, the text inside TextView is always different. For instance, it may be A1=70, A2=85, next time it will be A1=59, A2=70. Changing only the numbers, the letters (A1, A2...) are always the same.

Comment: will the values always be 2 characters on the string? like from 00 to 99? and A from 1 to 10?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like A1, ..., A10 should actually be members of an Array-like structure. In that case you can parse your string and recover indices and values alike. You would use a code similar to the following:

```
String text = ... ; //Obtain string from TextView
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);

while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
  Integer n = sc.nextInt();
  numbers.add(n);
}

// Make some checks on numbers.size()...

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size()/2; i++) {
  A[numbers.get(2*i)] = numbers.get(2*i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, about the decision that I found: I use "substring" and it's very simple to get a necessary data.
First I convert TextView to String:

```
String ratingStr = rating.getText().toString();
```

Then I get a part of this string. For instance, to get a "72":

```
String substr=ratingStr.substring(ratingStr.lastIndexOf("A2")+3, ratingStr.lastIndexOf("A2")+5);
```

Comment: Better use String.split() method, use it two times, once on ";" and once on "=" and you have everything split. Or even better, think about a more jsony way to save your data.